# What do the numbers after 秒 mean when counting time?

Tags: translation

I'm sorry if this is basic question but I just watched a movie that features a track and field event.

I saw people timing runners like "７秒３３" and "１１秒２２"

I just want to confirm if "７秒３３" means 7.33 seconds or something else entirely, since there's no kanji after the 33

Comment: Ah. I think so, yes. Thanks.